# cocos2d, reorder children in different batch node

Tags: cocos2d-x, ccspritebatchnode

I am creating a fighting game. I've got a spritesheet for the hero and a spritesheet for a monster. Since both will be able to do multiple attacks I would like to avoid to merge them in a single spritesheet. And I am intending to create more characters.

Now I am creating a SpriteBatchNode for each spritesheet and add them to layer.

```
CCLayer* stage = CCLayer::create();
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("character_hero.plist");
this->characterHeroBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("character_hero.pvr.ccz");

CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("character_monster.plist");
this->characterMonsterBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("character_monster.pvr.ccz");

stage->addChild(characterHeroBatchNode);
stage->addChild(characterMonsterBatchNode);
```

Now I have one sprite in `characterHeroBatchNode` and multiple in `characterMonsterBatchNode`.

How can I reorder the monsters and the heros z-Order based on their PositionY attribute.

For example>

```
monster1->setPositionY(10); // In monster batch node
hero->setPositionY(24); // In hero batch node
monster2->setPositionY(43); // In monster batch node
```

I want the monster 1 behind the hero. And the hero behind monster2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've had to create games where I wanted some sprites in the foreground and others in the background.  The sprites were in different sheets, like you have them.

To get them in the order I wanted, I put the "front" sprites into one CCLayer and the "back" sprites into another CCLayer.  I added the layers to the scene in the order I wanted them to appear.  I also manipulated each the respective layers to make them fade in/out as needed.  So you could have the hero in the scene and then have the enemies appear behind him.

If you want to mix and match, you can have 3 layers, one for the "middle ground", one for "front", and one for "back", and dynamically move the sprites between the layers.

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind. I am not sure yet whether 2 Spritesheets will be enough. But I will adopt it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, the answer is, you can't.  Consider each `CCSpriteBatchNode` to be its own container.  You can adjust the Z order of the sprites inside the `CCSpriteBatchNode`, but when you add the batch to the `CCLayer` the whole `CCSpriteBatchNode` is applied to the `CCLayer` in whatever Z order you added it at. So in order to do what you want you would need another batch of monsters.  Or use `CCSprites` and add/adjust them on the `CCLayer` in the way you want, but then you obviously lose the `CCSpriteBatchNode` benefits.

Comment: Since NonlinearIdeas posted a suggestion which works better in my case I accepted his answer. But thanks for the fast reply!